# Trigger Gallery OnFling without GUI Input

Tags: gallery, onfling

How can you trigger an onFling() without the user actually touching the device?

Actually my need is a little different than that. I have a horizontally-scrolling Gallery, and below that is a row of buttons. I want the user to be able to advance the gallery to the next View just by tapping a bottom-row button. Let's call this method next().

I envision calling the next() from the OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, there is a method available to Gallery. It is setSelected(int index).